# How to manipulate dependencies of NuGet packages?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package, restsharp

I'm a newby with .Net Development and facing the problem, that an available nuget package (influxdb client) depends on another package (restsharp), which does'nt include an important functionality I need (allow own signed SSL certs).

Since restsharp is opensource, I'm able to change the code and build "my own" .dll file, with the functionality I need.

But how can i "tell" the influx.client nuget package to use my own .dll instead of the native one ? If I just replace the files, VS throws an error because it wont finnd the file (prop. because the keytoken doesnt match?).

Comment: dependencies are transitive; to get that working *with package dependencies*, I *suspect* you'd need to rebuild/replace the entire dependency chain all the way up, however, I also wonder whether you could achieve your aim simply by hooking `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`; it may also be cheaper, in overall terms, to simply *buy a proper certificate*, than to spend effort trying to fix this with code

Comment: Man, I wish I would have asked this question earlier. Totally correct, thanks for pointing that out. A simple one-liner solved the problem I spend like a hole day for. Thank you very much! @MarcGravell